# VB.NET > SQL > HTML Tables, how to work with functions

Tags: html, sql, vb.net

On this form, the user performs an inventory search.  I have the results of that search displayed in an HTML table.

```
If rsMPCS.HasRows = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("No Item Found")
            Else
                varHTMLBody = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">" & vbCrLf & "<html>" & vbCrLf & "<head>" & vbCrLf & " <title></title>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & " <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=""text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"">" & vbCrLf & "</head>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<body bgcolor=""#FFFFFF"">" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<table border=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" style=""border-collapse: collapse"" bordercolor=""#000000"" width=""100%"" id=""AutoNumber1" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<tr>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<tr>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<tr>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<table border=0 width=""100%"" height=""200"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"">" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<table width=""100%"" border=1 cellspacing=0 cellspadding=0>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td bgcolor=""#000000""><b><font size=4 color=""#FFFFFF"">Part Number: </b></td>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td bgcolor=""#000000""><b><font size=4 color=""#FFFFFF"">Description: </b></td>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td bgcolor=""#000000""><b><font size=4 color=""#FFFFFF"">Quantity: </b></td>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td bgcolor=""#000000""><b><font size=4 color=""#FFFFFF"">Minimum: </b></td>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td bgcolor=""#000000""><b><font size=4 color=""#FFFFFF"">Cart </b></td>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<tr>" & vbCrLf
                varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
                While rsMPCS.Read
                    varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td><font size=2>" & rsMPCS("MTI_PART_NO") & "</td>" & vbCrLf
                    varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td><font size=2>" & rsMPCS("Description") & "</td>" & vbCrLf
                    varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td><font size=2>" & rsMPCS("STOCKROOM_QTY") & "</td>" & vbCrLf
                    varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td><font size=2>" & rsMPCS("MIN_QTY") & "</td>" & vbCrLf
                    varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td><img src=""k12169922.jpg"" width=""100"" height=""100""> " & "</td></tr>" & vbCrLf
                End While
```

In the "cart" column is a picture of a shopping cart so they can click the one next to the item they need the inventory dept to fill (this is all internal dept supplies, not external customers)

I'm not sure 1) how to make the image in the cart column launch a function.  And 2) how to carry only the information in that particular row over to use on the cart form that I want clicking that image to launch.

Comment: The image could be an anchor with the id of the row as a query string.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, just testing I have Form2.  And want the image in the row to launch Form2, I can only get it to launch another HTML Browser control with "Form2" as text.

Comment: that's a different problem, you should display that code for us the look and see what you did wrong.

Comment: This may be entirely wrong, should I be using something like this? But modified.

Sorry I don't know how to do the code blocks on replies

`Dim userLink as string = textbox1.text
For each link as HtmlElement In WB.Document.Links
    if link.GetAttribute("href") = userLink Then
        link.InvokeMember("click")
       Exit For
    End If
Next`